# Javascript onload function not running

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, onload

I'm trying to get the header to switch between the words "Board Certified Plastic Surgeon, Landon Keith" and "Landon Keith, Board Certified Plastic Surgeon" but nothing is happening and it looks like the `onload` function is not running

Ex. When I click the image the header show say "Landon Keith, Board Certified Plastic Surgeon" and when I click the image again it should say "Board Certified Plastic Surgeon, Landon Keith" and so on.

My code is the following:

```js
    var p = document.getElementById('pic');
    var h = document.getElementById('head');
    alert("oh");
    window.onload=function(){
     alert("inonload");  // This alert function is not showing up
    
     p.onclick = function(){
      if (sessionStorage["clicked"] == "true"){
       alert ("if");
       sessionStorage["clicked"] = "false";
       h.innerHTML = "Board Certified Plastic Surgeon, Landon Keith";
      }else{
       alert ("else");
       sessionStorage["clicked"] = "true";
       h.innerHTML = "Landon Keith, Board Certified Plastic Surgeon";
      }
     };
    };
    
    alert("end");
```

```css
    body{
     margin-bottom: 100px;
     margin-right: 20px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     background-color: green;
     font-family:Helvetica;
    }
    
    .navBar {
     background-colour: red;
     
    }
    
    #pagewrap {
     background-color: yellow;
     height: 280px;
     width: 640px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding-top: 25px;
    }
    
    ul {
     padding-left: 10px;
     background-color: red;
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    ul li {
     display: inline;
    }
    
    ul li a {
     text-decoration:none;
     color:white;
    }
    
    img {
     float: right;
     padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    h1 {
     margin-left: 25px;
     font-size: 14pt;
    }
    
    ol {
     margin-left: 25px;
    }
    
    p {
     margin-left: 25px;
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Keith and Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script src='js.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
     <div id=pagewrap>
      <img id="pic" src=image.png></img>
      <ul>
       <li class="navBarItem"><a href="#3">Reconstructive Surgery</a></li>
       <li class="navBarItem"><a href="#4">Cosmetic Surgery</a></li>
       <li class="navBarItem"><a href="#5">Awards</a></li>
       <li class="navBarItem"><a href="#6">Testimonials</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <h1 id="head" >Landon Keith, Board Certified Plastic Surgery</h1>
      <ol>
       <li> M.D., <a href="#1"> University of SomeState></a></li>
       <li> Specialization. <a href="#2"> John Hide></a></li>
      </ol>
      <p>
       Keith and Company<BR>
       111 Street Name<BR>
       Town, State, Postal Code<BR>
      </p>
     </div>
     
    </body>
```

Comment: Does your code reach to 'end' alert? Can you also check the console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Do you see any error on console? Press F12 on chrome to see the console

Comment: Pretty sure onload="init()" overwrites window.onload=function(){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inline `onload` handler on the `body` element is overwriting the `onload` in your JavaScript file (that is loaded earlier).  Remove `onload=init()` from your `body` tag and your external code will run.